# different CSS class for each column in database table

Tags: c#, sql, css

I want to give each column different dwign with classes (like in CSS).For example the column of usernames to paint in blue an enlarge font to 30px and to paint passwords in red and change their font into 'times new romans,12px'.
 I have the following cs code communicating with the DB in SQL:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class MyAdoHelper
{
public static SqlConnection ConnectToDB(string fileName)
{
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data/");
    path += "Database.mdf";

    string connString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=" +
        path + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

    return conn;

}
public static void DoQuery(string fileName, string sql)
{
    SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDB(fileName);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string fileName, string sql)
{
    SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDB(fileName);
    conn.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter tableAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    tableAdapter.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
public static string printDataTable(string fileName, string sql)
{
    DataTable dt = ExecuteDataTable(fileName, sql);
    string printStr = "<table border='1'>";
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        printStr += "<tr>";
        foreach (object myItemArray in row.ItemArray)
        {
            printStr += "<td>" + myItemArray.ToString() + "</td>";
        }
        printStr += "</tr>";
    }
    printStr += "</table>";
    return printStr;
}

public static bool IsExist(string fileName, string sql)
{
    bool found;
    SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDB(fileName);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    SqlDataReader data = com.ExecuteReader();
    found = (bool)data.Read();
    conn.Close();

    return found;
}
public static int RowsAffected(string fileName, string sql)
{
    SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDB(fileName);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    int rowsA = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    return rowsA;
}
}
```

I thought changing "printdataTable" but I don't know.

Comment: why do people vote -1 to my questions? Isn't it the place to learn from mistakes and ask questions?

Comment: you are correct and they should be giving constructive feedback as to why they have down voted. I would suggest it is because you have not given much detail on what you have already tried, and the question is very open. Do you wish to achieve the css change within the c# or are you happy to do it client side? of this that what you want advice on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a string containing your class name:

```
string classUserName ="class='username'";
string classPasswords ="class='username'";
```

You should change this part:

```
 foreach (object myItemArray in row.ItemArray)
 {
    printStr += "<td>" + myItemArray.ToString() + "</td>";
 }
```

to something like

```
foreach (DataColumn dataCol in row.Table.Columns)
{
   printStr += String.Format("<td {0}>" + row[dataCol].ToString() + "</td>", dataCol.ColumnName == "UsersColumnName" ? classUserName  : classPasswords);
}
```

or something like (if you want to use ItemArray)

```
for (int i=0;i<row.ItemArray.Length;i++)
{
   //if column 0 of the row (0 element of ItemArray) is the user name column
   printStr += String.Format("<td {0}>" + row.ItemArray[i].ToString() + "</td>", i == 0 ? classUserName  : classPasswords);
}
```

**EDIT:**

I corrected both suggestions:

**1.** in the first the error is "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Data.DataSet' because 'System.Data.DataSet' does not contain a definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Solution: Required the 'Columns" property to iterate correctly.

**2.** In the second it doesn't know the "<" operator

Solution: The row.ItemArray has a Length Property, not a Count one.

**EDIT 2:**

Regarding your second comment, if you need to add another column you could do something like:

```
string classEmails ="class='email'";

   for (int i=0;i<row.ItemArray.Length;i++)
   {
     //if column 0 of the row (0 element of ItemArray) is the user name column
     //if column 1 of the row (1st element of ItemArray) is the password column
     //if column 2 of the row (2nd element of ItemArray) is the email column
     printStr += String.Format("<td {0}>" + row.ItemArray[i].ToString() + "</td>", i == 0 ?    classUserName  : (i == 1 ?  classPasswords : classEmails));
   }
```

If you have more columns in the datasource than items in the ternary expression, the email class (last element in the ternary expression) will be applied to all other columns.

In this case, you should go with a switch, to allow other columns not to get formatted:

```
for (int i=0;i<row.ItemArray.Length;i++)
{
switch(i){
        case 0:
        //if column 0 of the row (0 element of ItemArray) is the user name column
        printStr += String.Format("<td {0}>" + row.ItemArray[i].ToString() + "</td>", classUserName);
        break;
        case 1:
        //if column 1 of the row (1st element of ItemArray) is the password column
        printStr += String.Format("<td {0}>" + row.ItemArray[i].ToString() + "</td>", classPasswords);
        break;
        case 2:
        //if column 2 of the row (2nd element of ItemArray) is the email column
        printStr += String.Format("<td {0}>" + row.ItemArray[i].ToString() + "</td>", classEmails);
        break;
        default:
        //any column you do not want to style
        printStr += "<td>" + row.ItemArray[i].ToString() + "</td>";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: VS said both of the ways are inncorrect. In the second it doesn't know the "<" operator and in the first the error is "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Data.DataSet' because 'System.Data.DataSet' does not contain a definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner Thanks for your input. I retested the code and corrected the errors. See the edit to my post.

Comment: Thank you for answering and editing again. even though the DataColumn still not working, the ItemArray works like a charm, thanks again. By the way: If I added column of emails that I want to be in another class, how do I edit the relevant passage (what to put instaead of `i=0 ? ClassUserName : ClassPasswrod` if I also use ClassMails)?

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner I don't know why the DataColumn mehtod is not working for you. I'm glad that the second one does, though. I edited my post again and included an answer to your latest comment. Hope it helps!